# Smooth a discrete delta function into a normal distribution

Tags: python, smoothing, normal-distribution

I have a one-hot encoded distribution over `n` bins, ie there is a 1 if it's in a particular bin, 0 otherwise:

```
test = np.array([0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

what I'd like to do is smooth it so that it becomes a normal distribution, with the peak in the same place but more mass distributed to the other bins, like so:

```
test = np.array([0.04, 0.2, 0.5, 0.2, 0.04, 0.01, 0.005, 0.003, 0.0015, 0.0005])
```

(These are just numbers I made up - the distribution needs to still sum to 1)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to generate the weights of a gaussian distribution which average is the position of your 1. Then you normalize it so it sums to 1.

You can choose the Standard Deviation however you like, it is the parameter sigma that is set to 1 in the exemple. A greater sigma will give you more spread-out values.

```
import numpy as np
test = np.array([0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])

def gauss(x, mu, sigma):
    # Since we're doing a discrete distribution, we'll normalize later. We don't need to add a 1/sigma/sqrt(2*pi) here.
    return np.exp(-(x-mu)**2/(2*sigma**2))

def smooth(test, sigma):
    # Handle edge case 
    if sigma == 0:
        return test
    
    # Get the average of the distribution - the position of the 1 in the input
    mu = np.argmax(test)

    # We compute gaussians weight
    smoothed = np.array([gauss(i,mu,sigma) for i in range(len(test))])

    # We normalize it so it sums to 1
    return smoothed / sum(smoothed)

result = smooth(test, 1)
[round(i, 2) for i in result] # [0.05, 0.24, 0.4, 0.24, 0.05, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```